# Saplings in a desert

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am surviving in a buffet world: floating islands, desert and constant night. Although i have wood, I am curious if it is possible to obtain saplings in this world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki lists all the materials in a biome: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Desert#Desert ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Desert&oldid=1548756#Desert))

The info box lists the directly included material and the structures, linking to the articles listing the materials in those and the loot chests as well.

The results:

- Weaponsmith houses in villages can contain oak saplings.

And that's it. Your only hope for saplings.